# Docker build crash due to docker-credential-helper

Tags: docker

I am using a script and in that script I'm building a Docker image. I pipe the Dockerfile to `docker build` as explained here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#pipe-dockerfile-through-stdin.

Here is my code:

```
docker build -t alpine-rsync - <<EOF
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add rsync
EOF
```

Unfotunately, I get this strange error message now when I execute the script. Can somebody help me what I did wrong?

```
free(): invalid pointer
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7ff4beae2e97 m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4afd50, 0xc420049cc0, 0xc420049ce8)
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0xe2 fp=0xc420049c90 sp=0xc420049c50
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice._Cfunc_free(0x2135270)
    github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:111 +0x41 fp=0xc420049cc0 sp=0xc420049c90
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice.Secretservice.List.func5(0x2135270)
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice/secretservice_linux.go:96 +0x60 fp=0xc420049cf8 sp=0xc420049cc0
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice.Secretservice.List(0x0, 0x756060, 0xc420012360)
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice/secretservice_linux.go:97 +0x217 fp=0xc420049da0 sp=0xc420049cf8
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/secretservice.(*Secretservice).List(0x77e548, 0xc420049e88, 0x410022, 0xc4200122c0)
    <autogenerated>:4 +0x46 fp=0xc420049de0 sp=0xc420049da0
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials.List(0x756ba0, 0x77e548, 0x7560e0, 0xc42000e018, 0x0, 0x10)
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials/credentials.go:145 +0x3e fp=0xc420049e68 sp=0xc420049de0
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials.HandleCommand(0x756ba0, 0x77e548, 0x7ffced22f7a4, 0x4, 0x7560a0, 0xc42000e010, 0x7560e0, 0xc42000e018, 0x40e398, 0x4d35c0)
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials/credentials.go:60 +0x16d fp=0xc420049ed8 sp=0xc420049e68
github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials.Serve(0x756ba0, 0x77e548)
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials/credentials.go:41 +0x1cb fp=0xc420049f58 sp=0xc420049ed8
main.main()
    /build/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-cMhSy1/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers-0.5.0/secretservice/cmd/main_linux.go:9 +0x4f fp=0xc420049f88 sp=0xc420049f58
runtime.main()
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x20a fp=0xc420049fe0 sp=0xc420049f88
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc420049fe8 sp=0xc420049fe0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.8/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1

rax    0x0
rbx    0x7ffced22dcf0
rcx    0x7ff4beae2e97
rdx    0x0
rdi    0x2
rsi    0x7ffced22da80
rbp    0x7ffced22ddf0
rsp    0x7ffced22da80
r8     0x0
r9     0x7ffced22da80
r10    0x8
r11    0x246
r12    0x7ffced22dcf0
r13    0x1000
r14    0x0
r15    0x30
rip    0x7ff4beae2e97
rflags 0x246
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but your command has an extra space in ```- <<EOF``` that isn't in the linked instructions example.

Comment: Create Dockerfile is not an option for you? Do you need create a dynamic Dockerfile at build time?

Comment: @DovRine: No `-<<EOF` does not help

Comment: @Aliquis: FWIW, your command works for me without the space.

Comment: @Aliquis: Have you tried that command on its own in a terminal? It seems like you probably have it in a script somewhere.

Comment: I tried your code. It worked perfectly. Also create Dockerfile is not an option for you? Do you need create a dynamic Dockerfile at build time?

Comment: Based on @meshde answer which does solve this  issue, I've updated the title to make it easier to find.  Piping the input into Docker isn't related to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/103), this is an issue with docker-credential-helpers and not with the syntax.

According to the issue above, this has been fixed in v0.6.3 which is available to download from the [release page on Github](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/tag/v0.6.3).

Alternately, as suggested by [this comment](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/103#issuecomment-457315596), you can remove docker-credential-helpers with the following command and continue as normal:

```sh
dpkg -r --force-depends golang-docker-credential-helpers
```

Comment: This does fix the immediate issue but I found it broke docker-compose, which depends on Python packages that depend on this helper.  Also `apt` will complain about broken packages after this, and its solution re-installs the helper.  Using a non `apt` install of Docker Compose may help - the [official install doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) does not use `apt` so it should not have issues.

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023 for more on the docker-compose / credentials helper issue.